# Swift regex configuration

Tags: swift, regex

I am getting strings like "hello @[dbe9234d-9e59-94b01-42342c9sd](user_name) how are you?". I would like to use a regex to extract the 'user_name' part of the regular expression. I am using the following regex, which is returning the whole expression (and I only need the user_name) part. Any ideas?

```
let source = "hello @[dbe9234d-9e59-94b01-42342c9sd](user_name) how are you?"
typePattern = "@\\[[a-z0-9-\\-]+\\]\\((\\w+)\\)"

if let typeRange = source.range(of: typePattern,
                                options: .regularExpression) {
    print("First type: \(source[typeRange])")
// First type: @[dbe9234d-9e59-94b01-42342c9sd](user_name)
}
```

Comment: To make sure you only match the GUID in brackets and then the username use `"(?<=@\\[[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{8}\\]\\()[^()]+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current regex [`@\[[a-z0-9-\-]+\]\((\w+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/9Xy0Zz/1) the username is in the first capturing group `(\\w+)`.

I think you can update the character class to `[a-z0-9-]`) using a single hyphen.

If you don't want to use the capturing group and your regex engine supports lookbehind `(?<=` then you could match:

[`(?<=]\()[^)]+(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/fIKvMj/1/)

```
typePattern = "(?<=]\\()[^)]+(?=\\))"
```

This asserts that what is on the left side is a closing bracket and an opening parenthesis `(?<=]\()` and then matches not an opening parenthesis using a negated character class `[^)]+` and uses a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that what follows is a `)`